# Unable to get Disqus to work correctly in a single page app

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, disqus

In my Backbone SPA, I am trying to integrate Disqus
So in my view's render I have added a call to this function :

```
addDisqus : function(element, pageID, pageTitle){
        if($("#disqus_thread").length == 0)
            $("#"+element).append('<div id="disqus_thread"></div>');

    /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
    if(_.not(this.disqusLoaded)){
        var disqus_developer = 1;
        var disqus_shortname = 'my_disqus_site';
        var disqus_identifier = pageID;
        var disqus_url = window.location.href;
        var disqus_config = function () { 
          this.language = global.lg;
        };

        /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
        (function() {
            var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
            dsq.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
            (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
        })();
        this.disqusLoaded = true;
    }



    setTimeout(function(){
        alert("reset disqus with "+pageID + " at " + window.location.href);
        DISQUS.reset({
        reload: true,
        config: function () {
            this.page.identifier = pageID;
            this.page.url =  window.location.href;
            this.page.title = pageTitle;
            this.language = global.lg;
        }
    });
    }, 4000);
```

I am creating the disqus iframe container only if it doesn't already exists, loading the embedded JS only if not already loaded, and resetting at every render with a new identifier and a new url which both depend on the new page. (I'll change the setTimeout by something more efficient when the code works)

My urls looks like localhost:8080/app#!pageID=23432 --> I have added the ! after the # like stated in the disqus docs

The comments **load, but they are the same for all my pages**. I don't understand why, because I use a different identifier each time which is based on the pageID.

**If in the "reload" function, I swap .identifier = pageID by .identifier = window.location.href this works**. But it is not the correct way of doing it, because a same page could be visited by different urls, and it would create different disqus threads.

What do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

As per the Disqus documentation, use a url with a hash fragment as a unique identifier:

```
DISQUS.reset({
  reload: true,
  config: function () {  
    this.page.identifier = "newidentifier";  
    this.page.url = "http://example.com/#!newthread";
  }
});
```

Note that both this.page.identifier and this.page.url need to be unique for each set of comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
  /* * * Disqus Reset Function * * */
var resetDisqusPlugin = function () {
    if (typeof DISQUS === 'undefined') {
        setTimeout(function(){
            resetDisqusPlugin();
        },3000);
    } else {
        try{
            DISQUS.reset({
                reload: true,
                config: function () {
                    this.page.identifier = newIdentifier;
                    this.page.url = newUrl;
                    this.page.title = newTitle;
                }
            });
        } catch(e){}
    }
};
```